# the app doesn't go to fulllscreen

Tags: android, fullscreen

Why don't my app go to fullscreen?

```
package com.rhyboo.net.gl_test;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toggleFullscreen();
}
private void toggleFullscreen() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}

}
```

I have the same function toggleFullscreen in my other project and it works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code always works for me:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your Activity's onCreate() method before calling super and setContentView().

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was is that android studio makes AppCompatActivity as base class for an activity.When I changed it to Activity it started to work.